# Plotly Map Choropleth not plotting anything - Streamlit

Tags: python, web, plotly, data-science, streamlit

I have the following dataset:

[image: Dataset]

I try to plot this dataset with plotly in a streamlit application.
Here is my code:
"PLZ" means the zip code and "Preis" means the price of something.

```
df = geo_data[['PLZ', 'Preis']].copy()
st.write(df)

fig = px.choropleth(df, geojson=counties, locations='PLZ', color='Preis',
                           color_continuous_scale="Viridis",
                           range_color=(0, 12),
                           scope="europe",
                           labels={'Preis':'Preis'}
                          )
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
st.plotly_chart(fig)
```

I used this as written in the documentation from plotly and I don't know why I am getting this empty map result:

[image: Map result]

Does anyone know what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
fig = px.Figure(
                     (px.choropleth(df, geojson=counties, locations='PLZ', color='Preis',
                       color_continuous_scale="Viridis",
                       range_color=(0, 12),
                       scope="europe",
                       labels={'Preis':'Preis'}
                      )
                 )
```

like in [this](https://github.com/ozgunhaznedar/swiss_renewable_energy_app/blob/main/src/main.py) example.